# JQuery let a div disappear after 5 seconds and then create new div after 10 seconds, but if the div is clicked on it disappears instantly

Tags: jquery, angular, setinterval, delay

I'm doing a project in angular for university and my problem is the following:

I need to code a football which is disappearing and reappearing all around the website. It should show up every 10 seconds and be visible for 5 seconds. If you click on the football it should disappear instantly (and add 5 gold to the account balance).

I already have this piece of code in the OnInit method:

```
setInterval(() => {
      if($('.football').is(":visible")) {
        $('.football').fadeOut('fast')
      } else {
        this.placeRandomDiv();
        console.log($('#minigame-window').position(), this.windowSize.windowHeight);
        $('.football').fadeIn('fast');
      }
    }, 10000)
```

This makes the football appear every 10 seconds. I tried adding a delay but then the football did not disappear after clicking on it. I also tried adding separate setIntervals inside the if and the else, but then nothing worked anymore.

My HTML file looks like this:

```
<div id="minigame-window" class="card-body" style="height: 65vh;">
    <form (ngSubmit)="addCredits(userId, amount)">
      <div class="football rotate90" [(ngModel)]="amount" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (click)="addCredits(userId, amount)">
        <img src="assets/football-157930_640.png" class="rotate90" height="80px" width="80px">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: If this project is using Angular, then you really shouldn't be using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
 setTimeout(function () {
      $('.football').fadeOut('fast');
      setTimeout(function () {
        this.placeRandomDiv();
        console.log(
          $('#minigame-window').position(),
          this.windowSize.windowHeight
        );
        $('.football').fadeIn('fast');
      }, 10000);
    }, 5000);

    $('.football').click(function () {
      $('.football').fadeOut('fast');
    });
```

But you should not use jquery with angular project you better use TypeScript

Here's the equivalent code in TypeScript:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.football')!.style.opacity = '0';
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.placeRandomDiv();
    console.log(
      (document.querySelector('#minigame-window') as HTMLElement).getBoundingClientRect().top,
      this.windowSize.windowHeight
    );
    document.querySelector('.football')!.style.opacity = '1';
  }, 10000);
}, 5000);

document.querySelector('.football')!.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.football')!.style.opacity = '0';
});
```